# Which data type to use when simulating NFA

Tags: java, types, nfa

I'm currently programming a simulation of a NFA with given transitions (in java) so I created an class NFA `<<S>A,S>` (A and S are the type of the Alphabet and the states) with a method `addTransition(S q,A a,S p)`.

With this I want to be able to add Transitions like `1 -a-> 2`. Later, the program is supposed to get a word and say in which state it is in the `end.But` I don't know which datatype to use to store these transitions in the method `addTransitions`. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: HINT: make another class `Transition<S,A>` with the constructor `Transition(A input, S destination)`